# C# failed to write cookie file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried to write a cookies file to store userID and userPw by the following code, but there is something wrong with my code, the output returned to me always is "cookies file not exist".

```
protected void writeCookie(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["save"] == null)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("save");
        cookie.Value = "testing" + "testing2";
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("cookie existed");
    }
}

protected void ReadCookies(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["save"] != null)
    {
        Response.Write(Request.Cookies["save"].Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("cookies file not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend storing a username/password in a cookie.

Comment: thanks you for your advise, i was confused about that too, maybe i will use system to generate a pass for user to keep they always signing in. but no matter how,i still need to create cookies first,so can help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx. Do not write out unencrypted user names and passwords to cookies, unless you have no reason to care about security.

Comment: any suggestion for me to keep user alive in my website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are your not creating the cookie in the first place, try changing

```
Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

to

```
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287547(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You are right, cookies should be appended to the response as a `Set-Cookie` header can be included in the HTTP response to the user agent. Cookies cannot be added to the request's cookies collection.